# Error expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Tags: c++

I have searched a ton of threads and cannot find a solution to this error. It occurs on line 8.

The BranchStaff.cpp file is as follows. It acts as a parent class for another class.

```
#include "BranchStaff.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

BranchStaff::BranchStaff(userIDIn, passwordIn)
:userID(userIDIn), password(passwordIn)
{
menuChoice = 0;
over = false;
while (!over) {
cout << "=======================================================" << endl;
cout << "|       Teller Terminal System - Branch Staff         |" << endl;
cout << "=======================================================" << endl;
cout << "1) Client and Account Management" << endl;
cout << "2) Change password" << endl;
cout << "3) Exit"
cout << "\tPlease choose an option: ";
cin >> menuChoice;
while (menuChoice != 3 && menuChoice != 2 && menuChoice != 1) {
        cout << "\tPlease enter a valid option: " << endl;
        cin >> menuChoice;
}
switch (menuChoice) {
case 1:
    clientManagement()
    break;
case 2:
    passwordChange()
    break;
case 3:
    exit();
}
}
}

void BranchStaff::changePassword() {

}

void BranchStaff::clientManagement() {

}
```

The .h file is as follows

```
#ifndef BRANCHSTAFF_H
#define BRANCHSTAFF_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BranchStaff
{
public:
    BranchStaff();
    BranchStaff(string userIDIn, string passwordIn);

protected:
    void clientManagement();
    void changePassword();

private:
    string userID;
    string password;
    int menuChoice;
    bool over;
};

#endif // BRANCHSTAFF_H
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BranchStaff::BranchStaff(string userIDIn, string passwordIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to not including data types in the implementation. Try

```
BranchStaff::BranchStaff(string userIDIn, string passwordIn)
```

I would also suggest passing in the strings by reference as using them in the initialization list should copy them.

```
BranchStaff::BranchStaff(const string& userIDIn, const string& passwordIn)
```

Comment: This fixed the problem easily. Can't believe it was something so basic. Thank you for the help.